# How to groung data based on quantify time series similarity

Tags: python

I want to group data based on similar data points. This grouping must be based on quantify timeseries similarity. I have finished,the first stage I calculated the distance using DTW. them the cluster into 3 groups using k-means. but I'm not sure what I'm doing is right or no. below is my code:

```
FPDataStanding1 = np.array([
    [6.59875],
    [6.76239],
    [6.45033],
    [5.79133],
    [5.56692],
    [5.57529],
    [5.67805],
    [5.87954],
    [5.93947],
    [5.80316],
])

FPDataStanding2 = np.array([
    [39.3875],
    [39.3033],
    [39.233],
    [38.8577],
    [39.1549],
    [39.52],
    [40.4228],
    [40.4586],
    [40.3507],
    [40.7479],
])

FPDataStanding3 = np.array([
    [5.35265],
    [4.7069],
    [4.94478],
    [5.63455],
    [5.99171],
    [5.25056],
    [5.16239],
    [5.42854],
    [6.04217],
    [6.1847],
])

FPDataStanding4 = np.array([
    [13.5343],
    [13.6674],
    [13.1456],
    [12.9966],
    [12.1601],
    [13.1042],
    [13.3396],
    [13.2633],
    [14.0001],
    [14.0524],
])

SIDataStanding1 = np.array([
    [1, 78.0, 55.0, 0.0, 0.0, 88.0],
    [2, 78.0, 55.0, 0.0, 0.0, 88.0],
    [3, 53.0, 30.0, 0.0, 0.0, 75.0],
    [4, 53.0, 30.0, 0.0, 0.0, 75.0],
    [5, 53.0, 30.0, 0.0, 0.0, 75.0],
    [6, 33.0, 70.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0],
    [7, 33.0, 70.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0],
    [8, 33.0, 70.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0],
    [9, 33.0, 70.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0],
    [10, 33.0, 70.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0],
])

SIDataStanding2 = np.array([
    [1, 120.0, 44.0, 0.0, 1.0, 88.0],
    [2, 120.0, 44.0, 0.0, 1.0, 88.0],
    [3, 120.0, 44.0, 0.0, 1.0, 75.0],
    [4, 120.0, 44.0, 0.0, 1.0, 75.0],
    [5, 120.0, 44.0, 0.0, 1.0, 75.0],
    [6, 120.0, 44.0, 0.0, 1.0, 90.0],
    [7, 120.0, 44.0, 0.0, 1.0, 90.0],
    [8, 120.0, 44.0, 0.0, 1.0, 90.0],
    [9, 120.0, 44.0, 0.0, 1.0, 90.0],
    [10, 120.0, 44.0, 0.0, 1.0, 90.0],
])

SIDataStanding3 = np.array([
    [1, 34.0, 55.0, 0.0, 0.0, 88.0],
    [2, 34.0, 55.0, 0.0, 0.0, 88.0],
    [3, 34.0, 30.0, 0.0, 0.0, 75.0],
    [4, 34.0, 30.0, 0.0, 0.0, 75.0],
    [5, 34.0, 30.0, 0.0, 0.0, 75.0],
    [6, 34.0, 70.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0],
    [7, 34.0, 70.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0],
    [8, 34.0, 70.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0],
    [9, 34.0, 70.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0],
    [10, 34.0, 70.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0],
])

SIDataStanding4 = np.array([
    [1, 78.0, 67.0, 0.0, 0.0, 88.0],
    [2, 78.0, 67.0, 0.0, 0.0, 88.0],
    [3, 53.0, 67.0, 0.0, 0.0, 75.0],
    [4, 53.0, 67.0, 0.0, 0.0, 75.0],
    [5, 53.0, 67.0, 0.0, 0.0, 75.0],
    [6, 33.0, 67.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0],
    [7, 33.0, 67.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0],
    [8, 33.0, 67.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0],
    [9, 33.0, 67.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0],
    [10, 33.0, 67.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0],
])


data = np.concatenate((FPDataStanding1, FPDataStanding2, FPDataStanding3, FPDataStanding4), axis=0)


data_flat = [ts.flatten() for ts in data]

distances = np.zeros((len(data_flat), len(data_flat)))
for i in range(len(data_flat)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(data_flat)):
        dist = np.inf
        for shift in range(len(data_flat[i])):
            aligned_data = np.roll(data_flat[j], shift)
            curr_dist = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(data_flat[i] - aligned_data)))
            if curr_dist < dist:
                dist = curr_dist
        distances[i, j] = dist
        distances[j, i] = dist

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit(distances)

labels = kmeans.labels_

group_1 = data[labels == 0]
group_2 = data[labels == 1]
group_3 = data[labels == 2]

num_samples = 10

SIData_group_1 = np.concatenate((SIDataStanding1[labels[:num_samples] == 0], SIDataStanding2[labels[num_samples:2*num_samples] == 0],
                                 SIDataStanding3[labels[2*num_samples:3*num_samples] == 0], SIDataStanding4[labels[3*num_samples:] == 0]), axis=0)
SIData_group_2 = np.concatenate((SIDataStanding1[labels[:num_samples] == 1], SIDataStanding2[labels[num_samples:2*num_samples] == 1],
                                 SIDataStanding3[labels[2*num_samples:3*num_samples] == 1], SIDataStanding4[labels[3*num_samples:] == 1]), axis=0)
SIData_group_3 = np.concatenate((SIDataStanding1[labels[:num_samples] == 2], SIDataStanding2[labels[num_samples:2*num_samples] == 2],
                                 SIDataStanding3[labels[2*num_samples:3*num_samples] == 2], SIDataStanding4[labels[3*num_samples:] == 2]), axis=0)

print("Group 1 (FPDataStanding):")
print(group_1)
print("Group 1 (SIDataStanding):")
print(SIData_group_1)
print("\n")
print("Group 2 (FPDataStanding):")
print(group_2)
print("Group 2 (SIDataStanding):")
print(SIData_group_2)
print("\n")
print("Group 3 (FPDataStanding):")
print(group_3)
print("Group 3 (SIDataStanding):")
print(SIData_group_3)`
```

the thing that makes me unsure because usually data coming from the same dataset will be in 2 groups.

[image]